# Migrating data binding from MVVMLight to CommunityToolkit.Mvvm

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, mvvm-light, community-toolkit-mvvm

I am attempting to migrate a Xamarin native (Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android) solution from MVVMLight to CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.

I have pored over documentation on this topic [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/migratingfrommvvmlight). The docs state that

> there are no replacements for platform-specific components

What are my options for addressing this gap in functionality? Specifically, I am looking for a way to programmatically bind observable properties to native control instance state.  For example, I may need to set up bi-directional binding between `MyVM.FooTextProperty` and `MyController.FooTextControl`.  This was achieved in MVVMLight with `Binding`, `BindingMode`, etc. classes and extension methods.

1. Are there any projects that attempt to fill this gap?
2. Is this functionality relatively trivial to implement from scratch?
3. Or is what I'm trying to do (use CommunityToolkit.Mvvm with a Xamarin native codebase) inherently misguided?

I've asked for some guidance on the [CommunityToolkit Github project](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/CommunityToolkit/issues/276), but haven't gotten a response.

Comment: Hi Sasha,Any alternate solution did you found?